# Graphs Isomorphisms Degrees proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[image]

Can anyone explain what this means maybe in a simple example and show me how to proof this? Would really appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: Hint: $2q$ is the number of _ends_ of edges in the graph.

Comment: I know that... is there a better hint?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose all vertices had maximum degree, then $\delta=\Delta$ and so $\delta p=2q=\Delta p$.

Now suppose that $\delta$ and $\Delta$ are distinct. Then we should have 
$$
\delta p\le 2q\le\Delta p 
$$

Does this help?

Comment: oh wow this is straight forward

Comment: Yup. No mystery here. Good luck!

Comment: Just a quick question (I agree with your proof). But I am not sure you mean maximum degree (we have no stipulations saying that there are not multi-edges). I think you mean all vertices have equal degree. I could have misinterpreted something.

Comment: @Joseph: My "proof" (I didn't exactly finish answering the question, hence the quotes) was more of a hint. First, I was assuming that this is a simple graph. I don't usually think about multigraphs (more than one edge between a pair of vertices) or pseudographs (edges that form loops) unless specifically stated. Even though, the "proof" still stands since the Handshaking Lemma holds for both multigraphs and pseudographs. We were given that the graph has some minimum degree $\delta$ and some maximum degree $\Delta$. All I did was assume that it was either $\Delta$-regular or not.

Comment: I see. It was clear that the result would still hold for both multi and psuedo graphs as you stated. Just was a thrown off by maximum. Thanks!